# "Effort has been made" or "Efforts have been made"

Tags: grammatical-number

I want to say

> During the past years, effort(s) has been made to ...

Since the scenario is that there are many groups of people involved, I am not sure which one I should use.

Comment: Coderzelf: are you asking whether to choose between the singular "effort" and the plural "efforts"? If so (or even if not!) can you edit your post to make your specific question more clear?

Comment: It would be of interest whether there were distinct multiple efforts to achieve a goal or that the effort was cumulative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Effort* can be used as an uncountable noun or as a countable noun in which case its plural is *efforts*.

> Much effort has been made.
>
> Many efforts have been made.

These are both grammatical.